# Firebase InApp Messaging Fail to load a test message[Resource bundle is missing]

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am new to Firebase and have integrated Firebase InAppMessaging in my app.When I start a new campaign in console and enter the instance ID of my app which i got from logs[as mentioned here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?authuser=3&platform=ios#objective-c], I am getting a alert popup telling Firebase InAppMessaging Failed to load [Resource bundle is missing], but I think I am receiving the message from firebase as I can see[There are 1 test messages and 0 regular messages and 0 Firebase Analytics events to watch after resetting the message cache] in the logs. So please can anyone guide why I am not able to see the exact message that I triggered from Firebase console and what is this error message about?

Comment: How did you integrate?

Comment: Thanks for replying @PaulBeusterien . Firebase SDK is been downloaded, added and imported into the project directly . It is an existing application, so I dont want to delete it and add it through pods so that it might cause me more trouble with other working firebase features which might also get affected because of this move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing this step from the [README instructions](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/ZipBuilder/Template/README.md):

*If the SDK has resources, go into the Resources folders, which will be in the SDK folder. Drag all of those resources into the Project Navigator, just like the frameworks, again making sure that the target you want to add these resources to has a checkmark next to it, and that you've selected "Copy items if needed".*